# *this emulation in standalone functions

Tags: c++, this

Suppose I have this kind of logging facility:

```
struct Identifier
{
    Identifier(const int id) : id(id) {}

    int id;
};

#define LOG(x) std::cout << this->id << x << std::endl;

class SomeClass : Identifier
{
     SomeClass() : Identifier(123) {}

     void helloFunc()
     {
         LOG("hello"); // will print to cout: "123hello"
     }
};
```

I want to use same `LOG` macro in my standalone functions. How can I create some kind of stub for `this`? To be able write code like this:

```
void standaloneHelloFunc()
{
    LOG("standalone_hello");
    // "this" does not exists here, but some magic do the job
    // and this macro must print only "standalone_hello" to cout        
}
```

Or maybe there is more elegant solution for this task?

Comment: "Some magic do" *the what exactly*? There's no `this`, so obviously there is no `this->id`, so what is `LOG("standalone_hello")` supposed to do?

Comment: It's supposed to compile.

Comment: if you want a identifier maybe look at \_\_FUNC\_\_ and the like.

Comment: @dipp: Oh, that's easy. `#define LOG(x) ;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution: Use the same name, just at different scopes.

```
#include <iostream>

#define LOG(x) do { log() << (x) << '\n'; } while(false)

std::ostream & log() { return std::clog; }

struct Identifier
{
    std::ostream & log() { return ::log() << id << ": "; }
    int id;

    explicit Identifier(int n) : id(n) {}
};

struct SomeClass : Identifier
{
     SomeClass() : Identifier(123) {}

     void helloFunc()
     {
         LOG("hello"); // will print to cout: "123hello"
     }
};

int main()
{
    LOG("in main");
    SomeClass().helloFunc();
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. This will do the trick.